# Replace value in DataColumn

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

How to replace column value when looping rows?

My DataTable has two columns, I want to replace the value of the first column on every row.
I'm unable to get or set column value. So far I only manege to access DefaultValue and ColumnName etc.

Even if creating new DataColumn(), I'm not able to set its value.

Feels like I'm missing some fundamental stuff here...

```
        foreach (var row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                // column Unable to get or set value
            }

        }
```

Running .NET Framework 3.5, should I use linq?

Comment: you should use linq whenever possible

Comment: To my knowledge linq requires IEnumerable<T> and therefor linq is not applicable in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `DataTable.Rows` implements only `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>` you need to cast it to `DataRow` in the `foreach` and you cannot use var:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        row.SetField(column, newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I'm able to set new value. I'll figure out how to get the value. Much appreciated the explanation.

Answer (score 10):

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dataTable.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
  dataTable.Rows[rowIndex][0] = "Replacing value";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    row.SetField(table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Single(column => column.Ordinal == 0), "new");
}
```