# Multiply all the rows from an entire column from a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable with several columns. I simple need to multiply the entire column 0 to an constant value. In my case, I am transforming this column from from Giga (10^9) to Kilo (10^3). In other words,

- I need that each value from column 0 be multiplied by 10^6.

(I wanna change all the rows from one specific column.)

What do I have:

```
    // change the freq. unit (from Giga (10^9) to Kilo(10^3))
    foreach (DataRow row in csvData.Rows)
    {
            row.SetField(0, 9999);
    }
```

As you can notice, in this case I am simple setting everything in the column with index 0 to "9999". How do I change to get the value of the column and then multiply to 10^6?

Idea (not working):

1. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951411/replace-value-in-datacolumn):

   ```
       foreach (DataRow row in csvData.Rows)
       {
           foreach (DataColumn column in csvData.Columns[0])
           {
               row.SetField(column, column * 100000);
           }
       }
   ```

errors:

csvData.Columns[0]) - foreach statement cannot operate on variables on type 'System.Data.DataColumn' because 'System.Data.DataColumn' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator

and

column * 100000); - Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type 'DataColumn' and 'int'

Comment: `csvData.Columns[0]` represents first column if the datatable. You can not use it as a collection in foreach loop. You want to change specific column value or multiple columns?

Comment: Try following : foreach(DataRow row in csvData.AsEnumerable())
            {
                row.SetField<int>(0, row.Field<int>(0) * 1000);
            }

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I wanna change all the rows from one specific column.

Comment: So Let say if you want to multiply values of first column by 100000 then you should remove inner foreach loop and write `row.SetField(0, Convert.ToInt32(row[0]) * 100000);`

Comment: Hey @jdweng, if I try like this, I get the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, it worked. The only thing that I changed is that I converted to double because I have numbers with points. Do you want to post the answer and I accept? Otherwise, I can post the answer.

Comment: The column is a string value.

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea provided by @ChetanRanpariya in the comments of the question, I was able to solve my problem like this:

```
    foreach (DataRow row in csvData.Rows)
    {
        row.SetField(0, Convert.ToDouble(row[0]) * 100000);
    }
```

Side note: I changed from "Convert.ToInt32" to "Conver.ToDouble" because my columns contains numbers with points.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only changing the values of one column, you only need one `foreach` loop (to loop through the rows).

All you have to do is iterate through the rows, read the value of the column, and rewrite.

```
foreach (DataRow row in csvdata.Rows) {
    row.SetField(0, row.Field(0) * 1000000);
}
```